# Running rebaseall on Cygwin

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin

I tried building node.js on Cygwin and that caused errors, so someone in #node.js on freenode told me to run `rebaseall` on Cygwin to clean it up. So I tried that and I got the following message:

```
$ rebaseall
rebaseall: only ash or dash processes are allowed during rebasing
    Exit all Cygwin processes and stop all Cygwin services.
    Execute ash (or dash) from Start/Run... or a cmd or command window.
    Execute '/bin/rebaseall' from ash (or dash).
```

So I closed Cygwin, went to Start/Run and tried `ash` and `dash` but got the following alert:

> Windows cannot find 'ash'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again. To search for a file, click the Start button, and then click Search.

So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try invoking `ash` by giving its full pathname. For example, if you installed Cygwin into `C:\cygwin\`, then you would type this into the Start/Run dialog box:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\ash.exe
```

This should start the `ash` shell, within which you can then invoke `/bin/rebaseall`.

Comment: If rebaseall still complains, check task manager for zombie Cygwin processes like sh, bash, ssh, etc.

Comment: @spoulson - I had `ssh-pageant` still running. I had to kill it via Task Manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Cygwin-X make sure the X is closed, not just the xterms.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin#comment287306_231617), using Win 10 and Msys2 from PortableApps, I went to Task Manager.

Given the large number of running processes, I sorted the list by the column "Command line".
There I found my ssh-agent (`/usr/bin/ssh-pageant`) from Msys2 still running.
I killed it, and then I could `rebaseall` .